# Showing All Rows With Null Join Result When Using GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, database

I am running the below query on a large table of users.

```
SELECT `Users`.`Username`, GROUP_CONCAT(`GroupAccess`.`UserGroup`) AS 'GroupID' 
FROM `Users` 
LEFT JOIN `GroupAccess` ON `GroupAccess`.`User` =  `Users`.`ID` 
GROUP BY `GroupAccess`.`User`
```

GroupAccess is just a relation table with the User ID and the Group ID's they belong to.

My result:

```
Username....GroupID
Test1.............NULL
Test81.............1,13,12
Test82............1,14
Test83............2
Test84............2
```

However, there are many other users with no group (Test2-80) but they do not show. How can I get the query to list all the users even if they have no group instead of only the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't group by a column from the table you're `LEFT JOIN`ing with. When there's no match, that column will be `NULL`, and all those rows will be grouped together. Instead, use `GROUP BY Users.ID`.

Another solution is to do the grouping in a subquery.

```
SELECT u.Username, g.GroupIDs
FROM Users AS u
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT User, GROUP_CONCAT(UserGroup) AS GroupIDs
    FROM GroupAccess
    GROUP BY User) AS g
ON u.ID = g.User
```